# Mixing JavaFX and Swing

Tags: java, swing, javafx

i am writing a desktop application and i like to use swing components since javafx doen't provide a tabbedpane component. I can embed my custom swing component with SwingComponent.wrap(swingComp); So i  have a swing tabbedpane which accepts swing components as child items. These child items are swing components too and they have two properties, title and content. Title is a string but content is a swingcomponent. How can i embed a javafx container again in those swing tabs? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that once you go from JavaFX to Swing using the wrap method, you can't return to JavaFX.

You probably need to specify a JPanel, then add the JTabbedPane to the JPanel.  Your content would reference the JPanel.

Comment: thanks for the answer! i've ended up with writing my own javafx tabbedpane component using custom nodes and control since there is no other way as you said.